# Constructing a user function with an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction

Maybe this is a basic task to perform but I haven't found any literature. I am performing a convolution of two functions:

```
f[x_,Sigma_] = 1/Sqrt[2 Pi Sigma^2]*Exp[-0.5(x/Sigma)^2]
`g[y_,A_,B_]= A*Sin[B*y]

ConvolvedFunction[x_] = Integrate[f[x - T,0.25] * g[y,1,2],{y,-Infinity,+Infinity}]
```

(I set the constants `Sigma`,`A`, and `B` arbitrarily here for illustration)

However what I want to do is have access to the constants in the functions `f[x_,Sigma_]` and `g[y_,A_,B_]`. So what I want to do is something like:

```
ConvolvedFunction[z_,Sigma_,A_,B_] = Integrate[f[x - T,Sigma] * g[y,A,B],{y,-Infinity,+Infinity}]
```

But this fails to execute, I guess because the convolution integral needs to constants before it starts computing. However it would be useful for me to explore the behavior of the convolved integral by having the function in the form of `ConvolvedFunction[z_,Sigma_,A_,B_]` so I can put it in a `Table[...]` etc.

Comment: Something like this? `f[x_, Sigma_] := 1/Sqrt[2 Pi Sigma^2]*Exp[-0.5 (x/Sigma)^2]; g[y_, A_, B_] := A*Sin[B*y]; ConvolvedFunction[z_, Sigma_, A_, B_] := Integrate[f[x - T, Sigma]* g[y,A,B], {y,-Infinity,Infinity}]; Table[ConvolvedFunction[3,5,a,b], {a,1,3}, {b,1,3}]` but I think you need functions that have finite integrals over infinity for this to work.

Comment: A few ideas:  use `:=` instead of = when defining functions, remove the tick mark from in front the `g[...]` and use 1/2 & 1/4 instead of 0.5 & 0.25.  Also, the variable `T` looks suspicious.  Using variable names that begin with capital letters can cause problems, though not in the case.

Comment: Hi @Bill Thanks for the reply, what is the difference between `=` and `:=`?

Comment: @LouisB Sorry! You are right! The `T` is a typo, it should be a `Y`. What does the difference between fractional and numeric form do?

Comment: The expression 1/2 is an exact value and 0.5 is an approximate value.  That's about the only thing I can tell you that I am sure of.  I recommend searching this site for exact vs approximate values.

Comment: Have you seen `Convolve[]` already?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less That solve my problem perfectly in terms of what I want to achieve programatically, however if I numerically integrate the result of the `Convolve[...]` it fails, while the numerica integration of `Integrate[...]` does not. Even though `Colvolve[...]` and `Integrate[...]` yield the same result functionally and if I plot them they look identical....Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't do tests because of a lack of a computer, but: should it turn out that `Convolve[]` cannot produce a closed form solution, I usually fall back to manually constructing the convolution integral with `NIntegrate[]` and change the `Method` as necessary.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less Thanks! What is the best way to select a `Method`? Or is this just a trial and error thing? But I still end up with being not able to access the two component functions constant's. I want to be able to construct `ConvolutedFunction[x_,a1_,a2_,a3_]` so that when I `NIntegrate[ConvolutedFunction[x_,a1_,a2_,a3_],{x,LowLim,UpLim}` I can play with `a1`,`a2`, and `a3`. But I can't do this if I generate my convolution with `Integrate[...]`. `Convolve[...]` allows me the functionality I want, but fails with `NIntegrate[...]`

Comment: To use the example in the OP: one of the functions you are convolving is oscillatory, so I would test any of `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`, `"DoubleExponentialOscillatory"`, or `"LevinRule"` as the `Method`. The docs for `NIntegrate[]` have a guide on how one might choose a `Method`.

Comment: For integrating a convolution: at worst, you might need to set up a double integral with `NIntegrate[]` at the outset: `NIntegrate[(* stuff *), {x, a, b}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]`